# Spark the best way to load data set in java language

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data set like this:

Result  categoricF1 categoricF2 categoricF3

N   red a   apple

P   green   b   banana

....

which I will then convert each element in each column into bit representation
for example:red will be 10000, green will be 01000 and then I will store 10000 in BigInteger array. I will do the same process for each element in dataset

what is the best way for this case to load data? (data frame, data set, RDD)

I need code in Java. Thanks indeed for helping

Answer (score 0):

Spark Dataset are similar to RDDs, however, instead of using Java serialization or Kryo they use a specialized Encoder to serialize the objects for processing or transmitting over the network. While both encoders and standard serialization are responsible for turning an object into bytes, encoders are code generated dynamically and use a format that allows Spark to perform many operations like filtering, sorting and hashing without deserializing the bytes back into an object.

For example, you have a class `ClassName` which contains all parameters you require in your data.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ClassName implements Serializable {
    private String result;
    private String categoricF1;
    private String categoricF2;
    private String categoricF3;

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public String getCategoricF1() {
        return categoricF1;
    }

    public String getCategoricF2() {
        return categoricF2;
    }

    public String getCategoricF3() {
        return categoricF3;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public void setCategoricF1(String categoricF1) {
        this.categoricF1 = categoricF1;
    }

    public void setCategoricF2(String categoricF2) {
        this.categoricF2 = categoricF2;
    }

    public void setCategoricF3(String categoricF3) {
        this.categoricF3 = categoricF3;
    }
}
```

Then to create Dataset of required data, you can code like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
                .master("local")
                .getOrCreate();

// Create an instance of a Bean class
        ClassName elem1 = new ClassName();
        elem1.setResult("N");
        elem1.setCategoricF1("red");
        elem1.setCategoricF2("a");
        elem1.setCategoricF3("apple");

        ClassName elem2 = new ClassName();
        elem2.setResult("P");
        elem2.setCategoricF1("green");
        elem2.setCategoricF2("b");
        elem2.setCategoricF3("banana");

        List<ClassName> obj = new ArrayList<>();
        obj.add(elem1);
        obj.add(elem2);

// Encoders are created for Java beans
        Encoder<ClassName> classNameEncoder = Encoders.bean(ClassName.class);
        Dataset<ClassName> javaBeanDS = spark.createDataset(obj, personEncoder);
        javaBeanDS.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @himanshuIIITian, As I understand I need to create Dataset using class. I have one more question, How can I sum the Nth column. For example: red is 10000 and green is 01000 and I want the result to be 11000.